# Engineering materials entity class

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, entity, properties

Are there any Entity Class like `EntityClassList["Mineral"]` to get physical properties of "Materials" like steel alloys, polymers, ceramics or composite materials

Some properties can be obtained from WolframAlpha

```
metals = {"steel", "Aluminum alloy", "Magnesium alloy", 
   "Titanium alloy", "Copper alloy", "Lead alloy", "Zinc alloy", 
   "Nickel alloy", "Silver", "Gold"};
material = metals[[1]]
property = "density of "
d = WolframAlpha[property <> #, {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}] & /@
      metals
```

It could be useful to materials selection in industry.

Comment: Wolfram alpha shows the sources so maybe you can use those sources directly. For example, typing = = at the beginning of a cell then density of steel, the wolfram output has at the bottom a plus sign next to "Wolfram Alpha" that links to sources. I am not familiar with accessing databases online.